# How to parse a column of strings from a text file to an enum. C#

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I have a text file which I can parse into object values line by line which looks like this:

454864.35 6780638.76 -2206.263 3.000000

452235.30 6780927.62 -2081.68 3.000000

456687.71 6781378.11 -1978.47 2.000000

455560.87 6781230.55 -2173.23 1.000000

454072.22 6781284.69 -2154.58 3.000000

453191.10 6781416.43 -2147.66 3.000000

451562.12 6781809.06 -2251.86 0.000000

454301.38 6781950.10 -2061.31 3.000000

The values I am parsing into an object are IndexX, IndexY, IndexZ and a value which represents a rock type(0-3) which I have created an enum for.

```
  public enum FaciesCodeType
     {
         Sand = 0,
         FineSand = 1,
         CoarseSand = 2,
         Shale = 3,
     }
```

And my current text converter method looks like this:

```
        public PetrelDataFaciesCodeModel FromFaciesCodeTxtLine(string txtline)
    {
        string[] values = txtline.Split(' ');
        PetrelDataFaciesCodeModel dataFaciesValues = new PetrelDataFaciesCodeModel();
        dataFaciesValues.IndexX = float.Parse(values[0]);
        dataFaciesValues.IndexY = float.Parse(values[1]);
        dataFaciesValues.IndexZ = float.Parse(values[2]);
        dataFaciesValues.FaciesCode = 

        return dataFaciesValues;
    }
```

My question is how would I read the text file and create an object value from an enum which is parsed from the value on index position [4] of each textline?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically your question boils down to:

how to read a string represented float value and convert it to an enum value?

all you need to do is parse that float like the others and cast the result to your enum type...

so in your case:

```
dataFaciesValues.FaciesCode = (FaciesCodeType)float.Parse(values[3]);
```